# How to format to keep 4 digits before decimal point

Tags: r, formatting, data.table

I have a `data.table` with a column that I need to keep the first 4 digits before the decimal point, see `dt` below. So I want to format my column so the entries below will be 9875, 0000, 0037.

I am using this as part of an acronym that I am appending to another column in my `data.table`.

Is there anyway to do this? Thank you.

`dt <- data.table(code=c(9875,10000,10037.5))`

Comment: @Roman not an accurate dupe, since that question is about padding strings and this one is about extracting substrings

Comment: That's correct @camille Thank you. I was too fast here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take the `floor` then use `substr`

```
dt[, code2 := {s <- as.character(floor(code))
              substr(s, nchar(s) - 3, nchar(s))}]

#       code code2
# 1:  9875.0  9875
# 2: 10000.0  0000
# 3: 10037.5  0037
```

Or use `%%` and then add leading zeros with `sprintf`

```
dt[, code2 := sprintf('%04.0f', code %% 1e4)]

#       code code2
# 1:  9875.0  9875
# 2: 10000.0  0000
# 3: 10037.5  0037
```

Answer (score 3):

An option is to format with `sprintf` and extract the 4 digits before the `.` with `sub`

```
sub(".*(.{4})\\..", "\\1", sprintf("%.1f", dt$code))
#[1] "9875" "0000" "0037"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using package `stringr` with some regex:

```
library(stringr)
dt[, str_extract(as.character(code), "\\d{4}(?=\\b)")]
# [1] "9875" "0000" "0037"
```